# Decreasing the throughput of a UNIX system

Tags: unix, distributed-computing, apache-storm

I am trying to do some experiments on straggler mitigation in Twitter Storm. I am trying to run some heavy background processes in on of the supervisor machines, so that the throughput of the system comes down. I am planning to run processes like audio files, video files, web browsers for a very long time and measure the throughput of the system. Are there any better ways to decrease the throughput of the system? or is it just fine if i run processes like audio files, video files etc for a long time to see a significant decrease in the throughput?

Could anybody of you give me some better pointers as to how i could decrease the throughput of a system?

Thanks.

Comment: Are those supervisor processes realtime? Running background on a realtime system does not do a lot to negate throughput of the realtime processes.

Comment: Yes these are supervisors which are running in real time. Why is the fact that running background processes does not affect these process? How should i tackle this issue?

Comment: Real time processes are not subject to context switches the way multiprocessing (like fair share scheduling) schedulers deal out context switches to low priority processes. In other words, background processes would get virtually zero resources on a busy system and so have no effect.  I am assuming background means lower base priority

Comment: So what is the best way to reduce the throughput? I am planning to run some heavy processes like launch media player, launch of browsers etc and may be i could do it in the foreground it self. Is it fine if i do it like this?

Comment: Running normal priority processes probably will not affect real time. We used to test real time apps by setting cpu affinity to a single core and then flooding those processes with work.  Since you don't specify what UNIX(es) you have, this means assigning those process to be allowed to use only one cpu, all the same core for all the processes, however you need to do that.  This assumes those realtime processes can run in a single cpu environment, they may be configured to expect more cores.

Comment: Could you please let me know what processes were you flooding with?

Comment: Also, could you please let me know how exactly did you configure your system to run all the processes on a single core?

Comment: It is completely OS and sometimes HW dependent. What OS & HW platform do you have? The systems I tested were real time job controllers running on V-Class 16 core HPUX boxes..  They ran real time and provided synchronization between the processes under their control.  It monitored and generated more or less running minute-wise B-state estimates for electric transmission systems.  The input was from scada boxes sprinkled over a huge geographic area.  (None of that is going to help you.)  The system  needed 16 cores to run easily.  We ran it limited to 2.  It slowed waaay down.

Comment: I am basically running one of the STORM components in linux virtual machine. It just has a single cpu core.

Comment: I dunno what else to suggest -  but running mplayers at normal runtime priority will not greatly affect the real time jobs, unless the real time jobs spawn normal runtime priority jobs and somehow wait for them.  Which defeats using real time to start with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time on this! I will try what you have suggested. If i have any queries, i will get back to you.